# Get number of entries per month in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, date, count, pivot

I have a MySQL database with booking reservations with two columns:

```
BookingDate (datetime)
Status (varchar with the values of Confirmed, Open, Unconfirmed, Closed, Canceled)
```

I want to count the number of entries per month with the status of Closed, Open, or Confirmed. I am going to be exporting this data with PHP into a chart later, so I will need to pass it on in an array.

What is the best way to do this in MySQL? I would like the outcome to look like this:

```
mm/yy -> # of entires
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%m/%y') `month and year`, 
       SUM(status IN ('Closed', 'Open', 'Confirmed')) `# of entires`
FROM `booking reservations`
-- WHERE city = 'LA'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%m/%y')
```

Comment: Awesome! that totally works, one more question - if I add another row of 'city' with the options of 'la' or 'ny' how would I only select la?

Comment: One more question for you: if I wanted to make two different outputs. One output as it is, and another output of the reservations that were closed, how would I do that?

Comment: So essentially having mm/yy -> number of closed/open/confirmed -> number of canceled/unconfirmed

Comment: @tony Add one more output field with another conditions: ``SUM(status IN ('Canceled', 'Unconfirmed'))``...

Comment: And how do I sort by date? oldest to newest?

Comment: Yeah, right now it is almost perfect I just need it to sort by oldest to newest.

Comment: If you need such sorting you must use `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%m/%y'), YEAR(booking_date)` (to avoid "not in group by or aggregate" error) and `ORDER BY YEAR(booking_date), DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%m/%y')`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select date_format(booking_date, '%m/%y'), count(*) nb_entries
from mytable
where status in ('Closed', 'Open', 'Confirmed')
group by year(booking_date), month(booking_date), date_format(booking_date, '%m/%y')
order by year(booking_date), month(booking_date)
```

If you want one column per status then:

```
select 
    date_format(booking_date, '%m/%y'), 
    count(*) nb_entries,
    sum(status = 'Closed') nb_entries_closed,
    sum(status = 'Open') nb_entries_open,
    sum(status = 'Confirmed') nb_entries_confirmed
from mytable
where status in ('Closed', 'Open', 'Confirmed')
group by year(booking_date), month(booking_date), date_format(booking_date, '%m/%y')
order by year(booking_date), month(booking_date)
```

Comment: Awesome! that totally works, one more question - if I add another row of 'city' with the options of 'la' or 'ny' how would I only select la?

Comment: @tony:  `where status in ('Closed', 'Open', 'Confirmed') and city = 'la'`

Comment: One more question for you: if I wanted to make two different outputs. One output as it is, and another output of the reservations that were closed, how would I do that?

Comment: So essentially having mm/yy -> number of closed/open/confirmed -> number of canceled/unconfirmed